# Unable to authenticate with app key_id and secret for smooch

Tags: smooch

- I have earlier set-up JWT authentication for smooch API, and it works fine.Now when I'm trying to authenticate using key_id and secret, it's not authenticating. Is there any way to enable both the authentication or revert back to key/secret authentication.

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you post some sample code to generate the JWT? Smooch only supports JWT-based authentication, what do you mean by key/secret authentication?

Comment: @michaels, Getting the following error. "Exception while invoking method 'getIntegrations' Error: Invalid JWT body. Cannot use account scope with app secret key"

Comment: In that case the problem is pretty simple. If your JWT specifies a scope of `account`, you must use a secret key with the prefix `act_` - you can find those on the Account page of the dashboard.

If you use a secret key with the prefix `app_` (found on the settings page of a specific Smooch app), then you must supply a scope of `app`.

According to the error, you are supplying a key with prefix `app_`, and attempting to use scope `account`, which does not match